# Why does max-width and width display a completely different result?

Tags: css, image, width, image-resizing, dimensions

I am working on my CSS skills and by watching Kevin Powell's video "How to use CSS object-fit to control your images", I couldn't understand why the use of either max-width or width would completely alter the result.
Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="card"> 
 
  <img class="card__image" src="//unsplash.it/500" alt="">

</div>
```

And here is the first CSS code (pay attention to tard .card__image 's width)

```
.card{
background: lightgreen;
width: 350px;
padding: 3rem;
}

.card__image{
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
}
```

On the second version of the CSS code, we switch .card__image's width to "max-width".
Now I don't understand why when we use "width", the image is stretched out and takes the entire width of the parent element it's inside of, but when we use "max-width",it's as if it no longer focuses on the parent element but on the image itself. It proportionally fixes the image's dimensions so the image would appear in full/no stretch, inside the parent element.

In result, with "width", the image is stretched out and takes the entire parent element's space. With "max-width", the image is not stretched out and simply takes whichever amount of space it needs to.

How come ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The difference between width: 100% and max-width:100% is that: First,
> width define the width of the specific element while max-width define the
> maximum size the element is allow to have [link](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/whats-is-difference-between-of-width-and-maxwidth#:%7E:text=The%20difference%20between%20width%3A%20100,element%20is%20allow%20to%20have.)